# Python - matplotlib polarplot issue - "posx and posy should be finite values"

Tags: python, matplotlib

I encounter a strange error with `matplotlib` after switching to a new system. I am trying to create a polar plot with the r-axis inverted. Thus, in my case running from 90 to 0. This worked fine on my previous system with the minimal working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
plt.scatter([randint(0, 360)], [randint(0, 90)])
ax.set_rlim(90, 0) 
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction('clockwise')

plt.show()
```

Running on my new system yields

```
posx and posy should be finite values
posx and posy should be finite values
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:83: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in reduce
  return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
posx and posy should be finite values
posx and posy should be finite values
posx and posy should be finite values
```

So far I have found out that the error is triggered by the inverted r-axis in the line containing `ax.set_rlim(90, 0)` (with `ax.set_rlim(0, 90)` is works properly).

My system setup is

- Debian 4.9.110-1 (2018-07-05) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Python 3.5.3
- Matplotlib 2.2.2

The old system was quite similar, I cannot recover the used versions tough. Is this some known bug in newer versions? I was not able to find anything related to this error message in connection with polar plots.

Comment: I think something got broken with polar plots. Can you report this at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues)?

Comment: I have not opened an issue because I am not sure it is actually a bug and I have already found a workaround which works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I did now a rather sloppy workaround by changing just the labels to range from 90 to 0 with

```
ticklabels = ax.get_yticklabels()
labels = range(80, 0, -10)
for i in range(0, len(labels)):
  ticklabels[i] = str(labels[i])
ax.set_yticklabels(ticklabels)
```

All the radius values also have to be adjusted accordingly. In this case 90 - r_value in order to be properly displayed.